# How can I get return value for partially matching another columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

In plsql for the below query:

```
Select b.geo, b.country,a.country 
From table_a a
Left join table_b b 
On LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(b.country))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(a.country)))
```

Suppose this above query is returning output as

1. LATAM  Colombia Colombia
2. Null       null            Colombia_group1

I need for **Colombia_group1** it should return **LATAM**.

Comment: That does not look like PL/SQL code (PL/SQL is Oracle procedural language); it looks like SQL code.

Comment: provide sample data and  desired output , otherwise we can't understand whats going on

Comment: So in Table A, in the column COUNTRY, the value is sometimes Columbia_group1? What country is that? Why are such values allowed in your table in the first place? And, if such values are possible, then perhaps they are also possible in Table B. What do you do if you have Brazil_group1 in Table A and Brazil_nogroup in Table B? Do you still want them to match? What if there are differences in spelling - Italia in one table, Italy in the other? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LIKE`:

```sql
Select b.geo, b.country,a.country 
From   table_a a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b 
       ON TRIM(UPPER(a.country)) LIKE TRIM(UPPER(b.country)) || '%'
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a ( country ) AS
SELECT 'Colombia' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Colombia_group1' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_b ( country, geo ) AS
SELECT 'Colombia', 'LATAM' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> GEO   | COUNTRY  | COUNTRY        
> :---- | :------- | :--------------
> LATAM | Colombia | Colombia       
> LATAM | Colombia | Colombia_group1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e7c8a3cfd1d6cea47fb9dfb690a56712)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE`:

```
Select b.geo, b.country,a.country 
From table_a a Left join
     table_b b 
     On TRIM(UPPER(b.country)) like TRIM(UPPER(a.country)) || '%';
```

Note that Oracle has a `TRIM()` function so there is no need to next `LTRIM()`/`RTRIM()`.